# Matching words between 2 words with preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find the part of string between the word "my" and "is" or "my" and "are" with preg_match_all, but for some reason, it doesn't find any match at all. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code:

```
$tempText = "My hair is black.";

if ($matches == null) {
$matches = preg_match_all('/my\\s+(.+?)\\s+is/', $tempText, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1][0];
}

if ($matches == null) {
$matches = preg_match_all('/my\\s+(.+?)\\s+are/', $tempText, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1][0];
}

echo $matches;
```

**Expected result**

```
hair
```

**Actual result**

```
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upper case "My" isn't matching with your lower case "my" because it's not case sensitive. The code below matches regardless of case.

```
$tempText = "My hair is black.";

if ($matches == null) {
preg_match_all('!my\s(.*?)\sis!is', $tempText, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1][0];
}

if ($matches == null) {
preg_match_all('!my\s(.*?)\sare!is', $tempText, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1][0];
}

echo $matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern: `/my(.*)is/i`